# Driver for cassandra jdbc

Tags: cassandra-jdbc

What is the driver for this dependency? Like for instance in postgres we have org.postgresql.Driver, similarly I am looking for cassandra

```
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache-extras.cassandra-jdbc</groupId>
      <artifactId>cassandra-jdbc</artifactId>
      <version>1.2.5</version>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

`org.apache.cassandra.cql.jdbc.CassandraDriver` This is the driver. But this driver is using Thrift to connect to cassandra which is outdated and not supported. So I ended up using another jdbc driver, which worked

```
   <dependency> 
    <groupId>com.simba.cassandra.jdbc42.Driver</groupId> 
    <artifactId>jdbc42</artifactId>
     <version>1.0</version>
     <scope>system</scope> 
    <systemPath>/path/to/Drivers/CassandraJDBC42.jar</systemPath> 
   </dependency>
```

Website to download the jar
https://downloads.datastax.com/#odbc-jdbc-drivers